# What does &#_integer_; do in URL SRC?

Tags: html, image, tags

I saw an `img` tag in some source code and I'm not sure what the `&#10;` and `&#9;` do, here is the example:

```
<img src="&#10;&#9;assets/img/banner.jpg">
```

I took a look online but the search results didn't turn up anything (possibly because of the ampersands and hash in the search term), and playing about in the console didn't reveal anything either.

[what does hash semicolon do in src](https://www.google.es/search?safe=off&ei=m1QKXL_-GejWgAaB6LfoDQ&q=what%20does%20hash%20semicolon%20do%20in%20src&oq=what%20does%20hash%20semicolon%20do%20in%20src&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20554.26228..27034...0.0..0.782.4002.3-6j1j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.fl-UPij99G4)
[what does &#num; do in src](https://www.google.es/search?safe=off&ei=V1QKXLfPC97wgAbAzYjoDQ&q=what%20does%20%26%23num%3B%20do%20in%20src&oq=what%20does%20%26%23num%3B%20do%20in%20src&gs_l=psy-ab.3...48198.49122..50019...0.0..0.434.1399.2-1j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.tSAAt3DhKUE)

If anyone could give me a pointer I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,

James

Comment: They are [html character codes](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) - they allow browsers to show special characters without having the specific codeset for them.  Looks like in your case something may have converted them wrongly as they usually aren't used in urls like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `&#10;` and `&#9;` are HTML character entities. Maybe unintentionally inserted by someone in the source code.

See more about HTML character entities from here:
https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp